# How to merge data frame based on date between two intervals of time?

Tags: r, date, merge

I'm working with two data frames. Data frame 1 includes a date, I'll refer to it as the `merge_date`. Data frame 2 includes two dates, start date and end date.

I want to merge data frame 1 and 2 together based their `ID` column and on whether the `merge_date` is between the start and end date in Data frame 2.

For example:

```
############## Make Data Frame 1 #############
ID <- c(2,4,6,8,10)
DF_1_Start_Date <- as.Date(c("1912-01-01", "1945-09-20", "1934-07-01", "1967-12-23", "1949-05-19"), tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d"))

DF_1 <- data.frame(ID, merge_date = DF_1_Start_Date)

############## Make Data Frame 2 #############

ID <- c(2,4,6,8,10)
DF_2_Start_Date <- as.Date(c("1911-01-01", "1944-09-20", "1933-07-01", "1963-12-23", "1948-05-19"), tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d"))

DF_2_End_Date <- as.Date(c("1913-01-01", "1946-09-20", "1935-07-01", "1970-12-23", "1952-05-19"), tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d"))

DF_2 <- data.frame(ID, interval_start = DF_2_Start_Date, interval_end = DF_2_End_Date)

########### Data Frame 1 and 2 ################
> DF_1
  ID merge_date
1  2 1912-01-01
2  4 1945-09-20
3  6 1934-07-01
4  8 1967-12-23
5 10 1949-05-19
> DF_2
  ID interval_start interval_end
1  2     1911-01-01   1913-01-01
2  4     1944-09-20   1946-09-20
3  6     1933-07-01   1935-07-01
4  8     1963-12-23   1970-12-23
5 10     1948-05-19   1952-05-19
```

I would like the data frame to look like:

```
DF_3
  ID merge_date   interval_start interval_end
1  2 1912-01-01   1911-01-01     1913-01-01
2  4 1945-09-20   1944-09-20     1946-09-20
3  6 1934-07-01   1933-07-01     1935-07-01
4  8 1967-12-23   1963-12-23     1970-12-23
5 10 1949-05-19   1948-05-19     1952-05-19
```

So that the IDs align and the `merge_date` merges between the `interval_start` and the `interval_end` dates.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution, using `merge()` and `subset()`

```
DF_3 <- subset(merge(DF_1,DF_2), 
               merge_date >= interval_start & merge_date <= interval_end)
```

such that

```
> DF_3
  ID merge_date interval_start interval_end
1  2 1912-01-01     1911-01-01   1913-01-01
2  4 1945-09-20     1944-09-20   1946-09-20
3  6 1934-07-01     1933-07-01   1935-07-01
4  8 1967-12-23     1963-12-23   1970-12-23
5 10 1949-05-19     1948-05-19   1952-05-19
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a non-equi join

```
library(data.table)
DF_3 <- copy(DF_2)
setDT(DF_3)[DF_1,  merge_date := merge_date, 
       on = .(ID, interval_start < merge_date, interval_end > merge_date)][]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sqldf` you could do:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select * from DF_2 join DF_1 on merge_date >= interval_start and merge_date <= interval_end")
```

Or as mentioned by @G.Grothendieck, more directly you could do:

```
sqldf("select * from DF_2 Join DF_1 on merge_date between interval_start and interval_end")
```

Comment: Suggest `... merge_date between interval_start and interval_end`

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

```
library(dplyr)
DF_1 %>%
  left_join(DF_2, by = 'ID') %>%
  filter(merge_date >= interval_start & merge_date <= interval_end) -> DF_3

# ID merge_date interval_start interval_end
# 1  2 1912-01-01     1911-01-01   1913-01-01
# 2  4 1945-09-20     1944-09-20   1946-09-20
# 3  6 1934-07-01     1933-07-01   1935-07-01
# 4  8 1967-12-23     1963-12-23   1970-12-23
# 5 10 1949-05-19     1948-05-19   1952-05-19
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `fuzzy_left_join`/`fuzzy_inner_join` from `fuzzyjoin` package

```
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(DF_1, DF_2, by = c('ID' = 'ID', 
    'merge_date' = 'interval_start', 'merge_date' = 'interval_end'), 
     match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`))

#  ID.x merge_date ID.y interval_start interval_end
#1    2 1912-01-01    2     1911-01-01   1913-01-01
#2    4 1945-09-20    4     1944-09-20   1946-09-20
#3    6 1934-07-01    6     1933-07-01   1935-07-01
#4    8 1967-12-23    8     1963-12-23   1970-12-23
#5   10 1949-05-19   10     1948-05-19   1952-05-19
```